# What forum is appropriate to ask questions on specific pieces of music?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-questions

My post [Opening chords of ABBA Super Trouper?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/133279/opening-chords-of-abba-super-trouper) was closed by the moderator @Elements_In_Space as being off-topic.
I clicked on their profile but could not see a way to privately message the moderator.

What forum should I have asked the question in? I don't mind if you delete this too after answering it.

Comment: It's great for [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room). About the only rule there is "be nice."

Answer (score 5):

Firstly: Hello, and Welcome to **Music: Practice & Theory**!

I’m sorry that your first question had to be deleted.  I know that’s not a nice feeling, but I did this for a few reasons.

#### Why your question was closed and deleted

The help page that I linked to in [my comment](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/133279/opening-chords-of-abba-super-trouper#comment250473_133279) says:

> If you have a question [that is] not about…
> […]
>
> - *transcription of specific works*, including identifying notes/chords/meters/other elements in songs
>   […]
> - *requesting external resources* (questions should be specific and answerable on this site; external links are for references and supporting material)
>   […]
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Your question was asking for either a transcription of the ABBA song, for an alternate arrangement (which would be primarily opinion-based), or a link to another version of the score, — so it’s definitely off-topic.  (This type of question is *so specific* that it’s unlikely to useful to anyone else.)

As well as closing the post, I deleted it because I deemed it irredeemable.

#### Meta

If you want to discuss how the M:P&T site works, such as what type of questions are on topic, or why your question was deleted, then the right place to ask is our local meta site [**Music: Practice & Theory Meta**](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/) (where *this* post has now been migrated to).

But, it’s advisable that you first read through some of the pages in the [*Help center*](https://music.stackexchange.com/help), such as:

- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)
- [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions)

#### Messages

Unfortunately, the Stack Exchange network doesn’t really provide a way to send private messages between users.

Comments under a post can be directed to specific users with `@user_name` syntax. But this only works for users who have already interacted with the post. For details see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).  If I had *closed* your post (rather than *deleting* it) you would have been able to direct a message to me with `@Elements_In_Space`, so perhaps I could have waited a few days before deleting it.

#### Where to ask

If your want to ask if there is a site on the Stack Exchange network that this type of question is suitable for, you could post a question on the general meta site: [**Meta Stack Exchange**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and tag the question with [[site-recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation)], but I’m sure there isn’t such a site — M:P&T is the closest.

The other music site on the Stack Exchange network is [**Music fans**](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com), but if you read through [their *Help center*](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help) you’ll find that this type of question isn’t on-topic there either.

Having said all that, (as Andy Bonner’s comment suggests) this question would be well suited to one of our chat rooms: [The Practice Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room).

Comment: That's a really helpful reply, @Elements_in_Space, thank you!  I'll look up the practice chat room as you and Andy Bonner suggest.